# How to know which imageview is clicked and change image

Tags: java, android

updated i try other options and i see a video on youtube with 3 ways of do this and works until i add the logic :

with this code:

```
public void onClick(final View imageView) {
    ImageView mypic1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.select1);
    ImageView mypic2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.select2);
    ImageView mypic3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.select3);
    ImageView mypic4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.select4);
    ImageView mypic5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.select5);
    ImageView mypic6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.select6);
    View.OnClickListener listener= new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(imageView instanceof ImageView ){
                imageView.setTag(1);
                if(imageView.getTag().equals(1)){
                    ((ImageView) imageView).setImageResource(R.drawable.old);
                    imageView.setTag(2);
                }else{
                    ((ImageView) imageView).setImageResource(R.drawable.new);
                    imageView.setTag(1);
                }
            }

        }};

    mypic1.setOnClickListener(listener);
    mypic2.setOnClickListener(listener);
    mypic3.setOnClickListener(listener);
    mypic4.setOnClickListener(listener);
    mypic5.setOnClickListener(listener);
    mypic6.setOnClickListener(listener);

}
```

all compile but don't work, if i add the toast only, works (only the message with the toast text)

Comment: where are you adding this code?? in activity/Fragment?

Comment: i have one activity called SelectImage and there the user can pick 1 from 6 and i need change the selected to other (its the same image but with a green signal)

Comment: First thing you have to set onClickListener to all Image View

Comment: you can not set final  v.getTag(); to ImageView because different type

Comment: can you share the code where you are setting the tag! And the answer i posted it should work.

Comment: i update the code again

Comment: `final ImageView mypic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selectcarta1);` there is no need to add this as you already have the View which is clicked in `onClick` just have to typecast it

Comment: ImageView mypic; if i delete the "final ImageView mypic "
i have an error called mypic not initialized

Comment: @AndresW How do you change the image after you've clicked on it? Its a different image, of just some selection style?

Comment: please put xml file

Comment: yes @fragment i change to other image

Comment: @AndresW imageView.setTag(1); will set tag = 1 for every Image View due to which else part will never work i.e 
else{
                    ((ImageView) imageView).setImageResource(R.drawable.new);
                    imageView.setTag(1);
                }

Comment: ok i understand but anyone can explainme how to do that? i want switch between 2 images ON/OFF only that

Answer (score 0):

modify on click like this

```
 public void onClick (View v){
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.mypic1:
                    //do you action against mypic1:
                    break;
                case R.id.mypic2:
                    //do you action against mypic2:
                    break;
                case R.id.mypic3:
                    //do you action against mypic3:
                    break;
                case R.id.mypic4:
                    //do you action against mypic4:
                    break;
                case R.id.mypic5:
                    //do you action against mypic5:
                    break;
                case R.id.mypic6:
                    //do you action against mypic6:
                    break;
            }
        });
```

Comment: i edit the main thread with your code and i have the same error    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Comment: in you xml write android:onClick="onClick" in each button.

Answer (score 0):

in `onStart()` of Activity of Fragment in which i have added the ImageView add below code.

```
 override fun onStart() {
    //get all the image view like this 
    ImageView mypic1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_imageView_id1)
    ImageView mypic2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_imageView_id2)
    ImageView mypic3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_imageView_id3)
    ImageView mypic4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_imageView_id4)

    .
    .
    .
    .


    //Set onCLickListener like this 
    View.OnClickListener listener= new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View imageView) {
            if(imageView instanceof ImageView ){
            //add all business logic related to your tag and replacing the image of the view
              if(imageView.getTag().equals(1)){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.picprevius);
                imageView.setTag(2);
              }else{
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.newpic);
                imageView.setTag(1);
              }
           }
        }      
     }
     //add listener to all the image View like this 
     mypic1.setOnClickListener(listener)
     mypic2.setOnClickListener(listener)
     mypic3.setOnClickListener(listener)
     mypic4.setOnClickListener(listener)
     .
     .
     .
     .

  }
```

Comment: thanks but you are using kotling and i have "cannot resolve" in all your code, i have other activities also in java i can't change all

Comment: if you have 5 minutes please check the main thread i update the code @Anmol

Comment: @AndresW if the toast is working it mean's the button click's are working fine you have to set tag's properly as the flow of your code is not right.

Answer (score 0):

hi you first add this line to be class

> public class test implements View.OnClickListener {
> ImageView mypic; ...}

you must be set var type to be cast

> mypic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mypic1);
>
> mypic.setOnClickListener(this);

```
public void onClick (View v){
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.mypic1:
            if(mypic.getTag().toString().equals(1)){
                mypic.setTag(2);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
                mypic.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.newpic));
            else
                mypic.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.newpic,null));
            }else{
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
                mypic.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.oldpic));
            else
                mypic.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.oldpic,null));
                mypic.setTag(1);
            }                
      break;
        case R.id.pic2:
            //do you action against mypic2:
            break;
        case R.id.pic3:
            //do you action against mypic3:
            break;
        case R.id.pic4:
            //do you action against mypic4:
            break;
        case R.id.pic5:
            //do you action against mypic5:
            break;
        case R.id.pic6:
            //do you action against mypic6:
            break;
    }
}
```